# Practical uses for compound literal expressions?

Tags: c, compound-literals

What are the practical applications of compound literals? I am not quite sure how an address of an unnamed region of storage could be useful.

```
int *pointer = (int[]){2, 4};
```

I found them mentioned here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal

Comment: One question per... er... question, please.

Comment: Question for the peanut gallery: would a compound literal be on the stack or might it be in static memory? The latter would avoid the risk of overflowing the stack as compared to `int array[] = ...`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: probably on the stack. 6.5.2.5/p5: "The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block."

Comment: Of course, the compiler might be able to optimise certain cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some great ones:

- Working around interfaces that take a pointer to input rather than a value (possibly to return an updated value you don't have any reason to care about):

  ```
  y = accept(x, &sa, &(socklen_t){sizeof sa});
  ```
- Implementing functions with named and default-zero/null arguments:

  ```
  #define foo(...) foo_func(&(struct foo_args){__VA_LIST__})
  foo(.a=42, .b="hello" /* .c = NULL implicitly */);
  ```
- Implementing custom formats for `printf` (automatically getting per-macro-instantiation temp buffer):

  ```
  #define fmt_mytype(x) fmt_mytype_func((char[MAX_NEEDED]){""}, x)
  printf("...%s...", ..., fmt_mytype(foo), ...);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Compound literals can be used for arrays, but they are just as useful to initialize structs, allowing you to put a complicated initializations in one line, making the code easier to read, and less tedious to write.

Like so:

```
typedef struct{
  int a,b,c;
  char *d;
}type;

int main(){
  type t=(type){.a=0,.b=1,.c=2,.d="Hello world"};
...
```

Without a compound literal that would have been at least four lines of code.

They can also simplify transformation functions:

```
typedef struct{
  int a;
  int b;
}twoInts;

twoInts swap(twoInts in){
  return (twoInts){.a=in.b,.b=in.a};
}
```

Comment: *Without a compound literal that would have been at least four lines of code.* Would it though? If you exclude `(type)`, i.e., with the designated initializer only, it works the same, no?

Comment: This is true. I was referring to the alternative `type t; t.a = 0; t.b = 1;...` The designated initializer has the same power as the compound literal in this particular usage.

Answer (score 0):

They can be useful when you don't have control over the left part. If possible, you would probably use `int pointer[] = {2, 4};`. But what if the left part is defined by e.g. an external API, and you want to assign to it? The compound literal would be an option.