# Why does C allow you to assign a value to a struct variable using "var = (struct NAME){…}"?

Tags: c, struct

Before I thought I cannot assign a whole value to a struct variable.

This is actually wrong:

```
struct Student student1;
student1 = {"Andy", 18};
```

but I thought I can only use:

```
struct Student student1;
student1.name = "Andy";
student1.age=18;
```

Today, I found I could use the format below to do it, whith prefix "(struct Student)", but it is hard for me to understand:

```
struct Student student1;
student1 = (struct Student){"Andy", 18}; // it is ok
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? The syntax you discovered was introduced with C99 and is called a `compound literal`.

Comment: The syntax of compound literals is defined by C11 in [§6.5.2.5 Compound literals](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5).  They've been a part of C since C99.  You could also use `student1 = (struct Person){ .age = 18, .name = "Andy" };` using 'designated initializers" — see [§6.7.9 Initialization](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9).

Comment: sorry typo "(struct Person)", it is actually "(strcut Student)"

Comment: thanks to Gerharh, "compound literal" I learn it.

Comment: This Q/A is quite informative despite being closed(!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61485211/practical-uses-for-compound-literal-expressions

Comment: You can also directly assign structures.  Given two structures in `struct Student a, b;`, you can assign a full structure: `a = b;`.  You can also return a full structure by value: `struct Student someFunc() { struct Student a; ... return a; }` and then `struct Student s = someFunc();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does C allow you to assign a value to a struct variable using "var = (struct NAME){…}"?

Because it is convenient and useful.

> Before I thought I cannot assign a whole value to a struct variable.

This is not correct. It has been possible to assign to a structure since at least C 1990, such as `a = b`, where `a` and `b` are both structures of compatible types.

The form `student1 = {"Andy", 18};` does not work because `{"Andy", 18}` does not form a structure. It is a brace-enclosed list with no type. The compiler would not know whether this is supposed to be a value for a structure of type `struct { char a[80]; int b; }` or a structure of type `struct { char *a; float b; }`.

In C 1999, compound literals were introduced, where you can write `(type) { initializers… }`. With the type supplied in this way, the compiler is able to interpret the values and use them to form a structure with a known layout. Then you can assign it using the existing assignment grammar, `a = (type) { initializers… }`.

Answer (score 0):

In your third example you are creating an unnamed object. This doesn't work in your first example, because the type (and thus the size) of the unnamed object isn't known.

Note, that you can perfectly write:

```c
struct Student student1 = {"abc", 20};
struct Student student2;

student2 = student1;
```

to assign a whole `struct` to another variable.

You can also use designated initializers:

```c
struct Student student = {.age = 20, .name = "abc"};
```

It is also possible to use this syntax to initialize a pointer, by initializing an array.

```c
struct Student * student = (struct Student []) {{"abc", 20}};
```

But pay attention to the storage class of the unnamed object. Otherwise your pointer might contain garbage, which will invoke UB.

Comment: You *can* write that, but by that time the "shape" (i.e. the type) of student1 and student2 are perfectly known.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The type must already be complete in order to declare the variables. How does that affect the snippet?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It is just imprecise writing; by “the type … of the object isn't known,” Caulder means “the type intended for the thing on the right side of the assignment, `{"Andy", 18};`, is not known,” not that the type of `struct Student` or `student1` is not known.

Comment: *But pay attention to the storage class of the unnamed object. Otherwise your pointer will contain garbage, which might invoke UB.*  There's no "might".  If the compound literal used to initialized the pointer goes out of scope, accessing the data the pointer refers to or the pointer itself **will** cause undefined behavior.  You can't [safely access the pointer value](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2): "The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, but the storage class determines when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: The storage class of the pointer is irrelevant.  And [you can't specify the storage class of a compound literal](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p5): "If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block."

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't see a contradiction, as I was talking about the storage class of the unnamed object, which defines, when it goes out of scope, which in turn determines whether an access through the pointer is UB or not.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: FYI, in the forthcoming C standard, you can specify `static` for a compound literal. Or even `register`, `thread_local`, or `constexpr`.

Comment: @Caulder: Re “which in turn determines whether an access through the pointer is UB or not”: Yes, it **determines** whether the behavior is undefined. You wrote “might.” It is not “might”; it is determined. Definite. Fully specified. The behavior of using a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended is absolutely positively not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Agreed. Have swapped the verbs.